# Javascript not found in Custom Control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET registration page made in a Custom Control, that has a Physical address and a Mail Address field, there is also a checkbox for if they are the same. This checkbox calls a JavaScript function that hides the unnecessary fields and stops them being validated. This worked in testing.

This control has been put into a website, and when it is run, and the checkbox is clicked, and exception is thrown "JavaScript runtime error: 'updateValidator' is undefined" . 
The javascript is on the same page.
This happens across different custom controls with different javascript.

ASP.NET Web page

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxPostalPhysicalSame" TextAlign="Left" runat="server" Text="Postal same as physical address?" OnClick="updateValidator();"/>

<span id="spanPostalAddress">
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPostalAddress" runat="server" Text="Postal Address: " AssociatedControlID="txtPostalAddress"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalAddress" runat="server" Wrap="true" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPostalAddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPostalAddress" ErrorMessage="Address is required." 
    ToolTip="Address is required." ValidationGroup="vgRegistration" >* Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPostalSuburb" runat="server" Text="Suburb: " AssociatedControlID="txtPostalSuburb"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalSuburb" runat="server" Wrap="true" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPostalSuburb" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPostalSuburb" ErrorMessage="Suburb is Required." 
    ToolTip="Suburb is required." ValidationGroup="vgRegistration" >* Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPostalCity" runat="server" Text="City: " AssociatedControlID="txtPostalCity"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalCity" runat="server" Wrap="true" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPostalCity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPostalCity" ErrorMessage="City is Required." 
    ToolTip="City is required." ValidationGroup="vgRegistration" >* Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPostalPostCode" runat="server" Text="Postcode: " AssociatedControlID="txtPostalPostCode"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalPostCode" runat="server" Wrap="true" TextMode="Number" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPostalPostcode" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPostalPostCode" ErrorMessage="Postcode is Required." 
    ToolTip="Postcode is required." ValidationGroup="vgRegistration" >* Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPostalPostCode" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPostalPostCode" ErrorMessage="Postcode is invalid"
    ToolTip="Postcode is invalid."  ValidationExpression="^([0-9]){4}?$" ValidationGroup="vgRegistration" >* Invalid Postcode</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</span>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateValidator() {
        var enableValidator = !event.srcElement.checked;
        var rfvPostalAddress = document.getElementById('<%= rfvPostalAddress.ClientID %>');
        var rfvPostalSuburb = document.getElementById('<%= rfvPostalSuburb.ClientID %>');
        var rfvPostalCity = document.getElementById('<%= rfvPostalCity.ClientID %>');
        var rfvPostalPostcode = document.getElementById('<%= rfvPostalPostcode.ClientID %>');
        spanPostalAddress.hidden = !enableValidator;
        ValidatorEnable(rfvPostalAddress, enableValidator);
        ValidatorEnable(rfvPostalSuburb, enableValidator);
        ValidatorEnable(rfvPostalCity, enableValidator);
        ValidatorEnable(rfvPostalPostcode, enableValidator);
    }
</script>
```

This is the View Source form the page when running in the browser. I have cut some bits out to make it fit better, but have not re-arranged anything.

[image: Source from webpage]

I can not take it out of a Custom Control.

Thanks for any help.

From what I can tell is happening, is that the  entirely is being ignored, so the javascript, although technically exists, its seen as JavaScript.

I had the thought about moving the JavaScript into and external file, but then the ClientID's don't get compiled so I cant reference the Validators to turn them off.

Comment: Are you sure the script is being loaded on those pages, and that the script tag with the function is before any of your custom controls?

Comment: I just uploaded an image of the Source of the page.

Comment: First of all, i recommend you to bind the handler to the onchange event when dealing with checkboxes or radio buttons.
Now try to define the updateValidator function like this: window.updateValidator = function () { your code... } and see if it's still undefined when the event fires

Comment: I have change the binding to OnCheckedChanged event. Definitely a good idea. Changing the function, I get an error claiming that I need a ")". Tried calling it ever way I could think of. 

OnCheckedChanged="updateValidator;()
updateValidator();
updateValidator
updateValidator;

am I just thick at this point? lol

Comment: In the script tag wrap the code inside the function between:
window.updateValidator = function() { ...code }
 And in the element define the handler like this: onchage="updateValidator();" and tell me what you get. That ) thing must be a syntax error

Comment: OnCheckedChanged="updateValidator();"
------------
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.updateValidator = function() {
        var enableValidator = !event.srcElement.checked;
    }
</script> ---- that's still bringing back the same thing. ----   Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Comment: Thats an ASP.NET compiler error, you're binding the javascript function to a ASP handler that runs on the server maybe? use onchange as the attribute name of the event, even if intellisense doesn't understand it. Another way to do it is on the server side, in the code behind of the page do this: elementId.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "return updateValidator()") , and remove the event handler in the ASP/HTML markup. Any of this solutions need the script to remain as i told you before. Hope this works!

Comment: All of these sound great. but still no change. When I change the event to OnChange, and the inspect the code in the browser, it doesn't exist. both when the OnChange is in ASP/HTML code and the code behind. but now I'm not getting the exception I was getting before.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to append the handler for the checkbox directly in the JavaScript script on the client side, and not to rely on ASP events.

For this

1. Remove the attribute from the checkbox element in the ASP/HTML markup.
2. Add the ClientIDMode="Static" attribute to the checkbox control so you can reference the element from the javascript code safely
3. Attach the `updateValidator` handler directly in the script tag, to do this:

After the updateValidator function put this code:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var original = window.onload || null;

  document.getElementById('checkboxPostalPhysicalSame').onchange = updateValidator;

  // Call the previous window.onload function to avoid loosing functionality from previous javascript code
  if (original !== null) original(this);
}
```

If the updateValidator is undefined error still shows up, try to declare the function like this:

```
var updateValidator = function () { the function code... }
```

or like this:

```
window.updateValidator = function () { the function code... }
```